# Linux kernel and realtek rtl8139 driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write driver for rtl8139 for linux 2.6 from scratch. I've already written TX path, but I have some problems with RX.

I put RX into promiscous mode and receiving RX irqs. I set RBSTART into physical address of allocated memory by kmalloc.

I don't know how to find out how many received packets there are and how long they are. 
I thought that ERBCR, CAPR, CBR registers tell it, but they are == 0.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? How to find out anything about received packets?

Answer (score 3):

I answer to my question myself.

The received packets are located starting at RBSTART. The first two bytes of rx-ed packet are status bytes, and the next 2 are length of the frame + 4 bytes of crc.

Maybye someone find this info helpful.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this?

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure but probably I researched this info on my own - without any documentation.

Comment: I am developing an RTL8139 driver in Rust, and while testing I am sending a 46 byte packet from one qemu process to another. Now what is written in the RxBuffer is as follows.                                                                                                                   2 byte header + 2 byte packet length(=64) + <My 46 byte packet> + <padded zeroes until byte 64> + 4 bytes (crc presumably) + 4 bytes (all zeros). I don't understand why zeroes are there in the end. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

On receiving a packet, the data received from the line is stored in the receive FIFO. When Early Receive Threshold is met, the data is moved from FIFO to Recieve Buffer.

So, once you get an interrupt. You need to check the Interrupt Status Register for ROK. Then check the Early Rx status register  which gives you the status of the packet received. If EROK is set, then  check the Receive buffer status for ROK. Check for are any errors in the ISR and ERSR. Also check your Rx Configuration register for the threshold configuration for Rx FIFO, RX buf length.

Comment: But how to recognize where the packet has been stored in memory and how long is it?